# How to automate testing function with click handler that have async await inside the function using karma-jasmine?

Tags: javascript, async-await, jasmine, karma-jasmine, lit

So i'm trying to testing on my button that run the function asynchronously. this is my button logic looks like.

```
    // Function below will run when user click the button
    this._pageModule.favoriteButtonCallback = async () => {
      try {
        // I want to expect run after this await below is done
        await this._favoriteRestaurants.PutRestaurant(this._restaurant);
        console.log(
          'console log in button',
          await this._favoriteRestaurants.GetAllRestaurant(),
        );
        this._renderButton();
        return Promise.resolve(
          `Success add ${this._restaurant.name} to favorite!`,
        );
      } catch (err) {
        this._renderButton();
        return Promise.reject(
          new Error(
            `Failed add ${this._restaurant.name} to favorite! Error: ${err}`,
          ).message,
        );
      }
    };
```

and this is my test

```
fit('should be able to add the restaurant to favorite', async () => {
    expect((await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant()).length).toEqual(0);

    // spyOn(RestaurantIdb, 'PutRestaurant');

    document.body.innerHTML = `<detail-module></detail-module>
    <modal-element></modal-element>`;

    const pageModule = document.querySelector('detail-module');

    await FavoriteButtonInitiator.init({
      pageModule,
      restaurant,
      favoriteRestaurants: RestaurantIdb,
    });

    pageModule.restaurantDetail = restaurant;

    await pageModule.updateComplete;

    const favoriteButton = pageModule.shadowRoot
      .querySelector('[aria-label="favorite this restaurant"]')
      .shadowRoot.querySelector('button');

    // 1. Simulate user click the button
    favoriteButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    // expect(RestaurantIdb.PutRestaurant).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const restaurants = await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant();
    console.log('console log from test', restaurants);
    expect(restaurants).toEqual([restaurant]);
  });
```

i'm using lit-element, simply it similar with react, i have custom element <define-module> with button inside. then i give the required properties to it, then it will render.

This is my test log [Test log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Koi.png)

as you can see the console log from the test ran before the console log that i put in the button. and it is empty array.

what i want is when click event dispatched. the next line in the test wait until the asynchronous function in the button done, how do i make it possible?

What have i done:
i have tried to console log them.
i have tried to using done in jasmine, but it doesn't work since i using async/await in the test.
I have tried use spyOn, but i don't really understand how to spy indexedDb

**UPDATE**

So i have found what caused problem, here i have simplified my code.

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { openDB } from 'idb';
import { CONFIG } from '../src/scripts/globals';

const { DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, OBJECT_STORE_NAME } = CONFIG;

const dbPromise = openDB(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, {
  upgrade(database) {
    database.createObjectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'id' });
  },
});

const RestaurantIdb = {
  async GetRestaurant(id) {
    return (await dbPromise).get(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, id);
  },
  async GetAllRestaurant() {
    return (await dbPromise).getAll(OBJECT_STORE_NAME);
  },
  async PutRestaurant(restaurant) {
    if (await this.GetRestaurant(restaurant.id)) {
      return Promise.reject(
        new Error('This restauant is already in your favorite!').message,
      );
    }
    return (await dbPromise).put(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, restaurant);
  },
  async DeleteRestaurant(id) {
    if (await this.GetRestaurant(id)) {
      return (await dbPromise).delete(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, id);
    }
    return Promise.reject(
      new Error('This restauant is not in favorite!').message,
    );
  },
};

describe('Testing RestaurantIdb', () => {
  const removeAllRestaurant = async () => {
    const restaurants = await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant();

    for (const { id } of restaurants) {
      await RestaurantIdb.DeleteRestaurant(id);
    }
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await removeAllRestaurant();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await removeAllRestaurant();
  });

  it('should add restaurant', async () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<button></button>`;

    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      await RestaurantIdb.PutRestaurant({ id: 1 });
    });

    button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    setTimeout(async () => {
      const restaurants = await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant();
      console.log('console log in test', restaurants);

      expect(restaurants).toEqual([{ id: 1 }]);
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

And this is the result [Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSOzh.png)

I assume that IndexedDb takes times to put my restaurant data. and i still can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Angular, you would have access to `fixture.whenStable()`, and `fakeAsync and tick()` which wait until promises are resolved before carrying forward with the test.

In this scenario, I would try wrapping what you have in the test in a `setTimeout`

```
fit('should be able to add the restaurant to favorite', async () => {
    expect((await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant()).length).toEqual(0);

    // spyOn(RestaurantIdb, 'PutRestaurant');

    document.body.innerHTML = `<detail-module></detail-module>
    <modal-element></modal-element>`;

    const pageModule = document.querySelector('detail-module');

    await FavoriteButtonInitiator.init({
      pageModule,
      restaurant,
      favoriteRestaurants: RestaurantIdb,
    });

    pageModule.restaurantDetail = restaurant;

    await pageModule.updateComplete;

    const favoriteButton = pageModule.shadowRoot
      .querySelector('[aria-label="favorite this restaurant"]')
      .shadowRoot.querySelector('button');

    // 1. Simulate user click the button
    favoriteButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    // expect(RestaurantIdb.PutRestaurant).toHaveBeenCalled();
    setTimeout(() => {
     const restaurants = await RestaurantIdb.GetAllRestaurant();
     console.log('console log from test', restaurants);
     expect(restaurants).toEqual([restaurant]);
    }, 0);
  });
```

The things in the `setTimeout` should hopefully happen after the asynchronous task of the button click since promises are microtasks and `setTimeout` is a macrotask and microtasks have higher priority than macrotasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

My project doesn't using any framework. And i have tried using setTimeout but it seems not working. But i have found what is causing the problem, i have updated my question